# Comparing significance level to p-value in a two sided test

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, p-value, hypothesis-test, significance

I had a p-value of 0.608.
**For a two-sided test scenario,**
If I take 95% confidence i.e. 5% significance or alpha = 0.05,

In that case,
should we say, the answer to task be:

"0.608 > 0.025, therefore, we cannot reject null hypothesis.??"

OR, we should say:

"0.608 > 0.05, therefore, we cannot reject null hypothesis.??"

It was my understanding (inference mostly) that, assuming the data is standard normal distributed, you divide the alpha(or significance level) by two if it is a two sided test, before comparing it with p-value.??

Please correct my understanding? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I went on to check online calculater for p-value and decision maker.

While decision making, for 2 tailed test, the online calculator compared the p-value to that value of significance itself,

Thus, we can say,
"0.608 > 0.05, therefore, we cannot reject null hypothesis" is the correct statement to make, considering 5% significance.

Note:- We divide alpha/2 for 2 tailed test, when we calculate z_critical or t_critical from the standard z-table or t-table!
Thanks.